# Append comma to every element in the Arraylist of strings

Tags: powershell

I need to append comma to every string , my code appending "," to last element as well how to eliminate that

```
for($j=0; $j -lt $back_log_bloblist.Count; $j++){
        if($back_log_bloblist[$j].Name -like "$Value"){
            $string += $back_log_bloblist[$j].Name +","
            Write-Host $string
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are you ACTUALLY trying to do? not the comas, what is the GOAL you are trying to achieve. it sounds like you are trying to _manually_ build a csv file ... and that is almost always a bad idea. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved much easier without an explicit loop:

```
$string = ($back_log_bloblist.Name -like $Value) -join ','
```

**Explanation:**

- `$back_log_bloblist.Name` creates an array from the values of the `Name` property of all `$back_log_bloblist` elements
- `-like $Value` selects all elements from this array that match pattern in `$Value`
- `-join ','` finally joins all selected elements (inserting commas only between elements, not after, exactly what you want)
- you could remove the brackets, they are just there for conceptual clarity

**Proof-of-concept:**

```
$back_log_bloblist = [pscustomobject]@{ Name='foo' }, 
                     [pscustomobject]@{ Name='fop' }, 
                     [pscustomobject]@{ Name='bar' }

$Value = 'f*'
$string = ($back_log_bloblist.Name -like $Value) -join ','
$string
```

**Output:**

```text
foo,fop
```